# Cannot resolve method, why?

Tags: java, android, methods

The method `setDateListener(DateListener dl)` cannot be resolved. It is public and I am using it on an object of the class DatePickerFragment.java where the method is contained.

Here is the `onCreateView()` method in the fragment where the `setDateListener()` method is called:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up_about, container, false);

    mFirstNameEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_first_name_edit_text);
    mLastNameEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_last_name_edit_text);
    mBirthdayEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_birthday_edit_text);
    mContinueButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_continue_2_button);

    mBirthdayEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePickerFragment.setDateListener(SignUpAboutFragment.this);
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the **DatePickerFragment.java** class (imports have been omitted):

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private DateListener mCallback;

    public interface DateListener {
        void onDateSelected(String formattedDate);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        mCallback.onDateSelected(formattedDate);
    }

    public void setDateListener(DateListener dateListener) {
        mCallback = dateListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you implemented the interface in `SignUpAboutFragment`?

Comment: What declared type has `datePickerFragment`?

Comment: there is no interface SignUpAboutFragment.

Comment: It has type DialogFragment

Comment: So check @Blackbelt answer

Comment: All done. Thanks guys!

Comment: is there a reason that you aren't using `DatePickerDialog` as it is provided by google.

Also, that is a terrible way to pass info between a fragment and it's parent. As soon as the fragment is recreated (rotation, etc.), it will lose that listener and you will have an npe when you try and call it. Instead, it is best to have the interface on the parent and then in the child call `getActivity()`/`getParent()` and cast them to the interface.

Comment: Well dude I am only 16 and self taught. And could you refer me to an example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method setDateListener(DateListener dl) cannot be resolved. It is
>   public and I am using it on an object of the class
>   DatePickerFragment.java where the method is contained.

that happens when you assign the reference to the super type. `DatePickerFragment` is a `DialogFragment`, conversely a `DialogFragment` is not a `DatePickerFragment`

Comment: ok thanks so I just changed the type to DatePickerFragment and it worked! Cool. =)

Comment: If this solution solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted answer so it can help others